# Simple Alert in Android for Unity Plugin

Tags: c#, java, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an Android Plugin for Unity, and it's going fine as long as i don't need the current context. But if i try to open a simple alert box, the app crashes. Anyone any idea what i am doing wrong? it seems not so hard...

Code in Java:

```
public static void openAlert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(UnityPlayer.currentActivity).setTitle("Test").setMessage("This is an alert box!").setNeutralButton("Ok", null).show(); 
}
```

from unity, i'm doing the following (c#):

```
using (AndroidJavaClass myUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {

     using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = myUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {

            AndroidJavaClass myActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.bundlename.appname.SampleClass");

            myActivity.CallStatic("openAlert");

    }
}
```

Since for some reason i don't get the crash messages from the device, it's a blind flight. I am new to c# and java development so excuse me if this is a stupid question.

Best

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

First, anything you do that will modify the User Interface, such as Messages, Dialogs, Labels ... etc. should only be done from the main thread.

I dont know where the call your making is coming from, but if its not the main thread you may run into issues like this.

This video set helped me to build my android plugins.

Here is the playlist, he goes through the whole gambit. Ill start you off on the first android video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1Mle2ERiuQ&list=PLf8PfKIJPGkjhMgylU87G5A0JLMSy_8ad

There are 3 android videos and all the examples work, just watch them in high definition so you can read the code being typed.